# How to fix @JsonKey object null in @JsonSerializable?

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serialization

Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast,

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart'; 
part 'jump.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Jump extends Object {
  @JsonKey(name: 'des', defaultValue: '')
  String des;
  @JsonKey(name: 'shareInfo')
  ShareInfo shareInfo;
  Jump(this.des,this.shareInfo);
  factory Jump.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> srcJson) => _$JumpFromJson(srcJson);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$JumpToJson(this);
}
```

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND
part 'jump.dart';

import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart'; 

Jump _$JumpFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Jump(
    json['des'] as String? ?? '',
    ShareInfo.fromJson(json['shareInfo'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}
```

When shareInfo is null, causing an error in ShareInfo.fromJson(json['shareInfo'] as Map<String, dynamic>)，

Please tell me how to fix it？

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark ShareInfo as nullable like this:

```
@JsonKey(name: 'shareInfo')
ShareInfo? shareInfo;
```